# Adobe Air and Canvas not working

Tags: javascript, html, air

This should be a simple Air App. I am using Dreamweaver CS5.5 and creating an Air App. I cannot get the Canvas to load an image on function. I can get the image to load onLoad. The objective is to get an image to draw on canvas then resize and toDataURL to an img tag. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script>
function getImage(url){
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.src=url;
img.onload = function(){
context.drawImage(img, 0,0,width,height);

var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL();
document.getElementById('image').src = dataurl;
};

var MAX_WIDTH = 140;
var MAX_HEIGHT = 200;
var width = img.width;
var height = img.height;

if (width > height) {
  if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
    height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
    width = MAX_WIDTH;
  }
} else {
  if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
    width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
    height = MAX_HEIGHT;
  }
}

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<img id="image" src="" />
<button onClick="javascript:getImage('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png');">Get Image</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the that line is giving you problems:

```
<button onClick="javascript:getImage('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png');">Get Image</button>
```

The code defined in a link using the javascript: URL scheme is ignored in the application sandbox. No unsafe JavaScript error is generated.